# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.signals' has no attribute 'post_syncdb'

Tags: python, django

I created two models in my Django db. Now, I want to make migrations, but it shows error like this: `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.signals' has no attribute 'post_syncdb'` . I tried to google the answer and found that this signal was deprecated in new Django version. It is not my project and I can't change the current version, so my colleagues recommended me to find the solution. What am I supposed to do if I can't change the version of Django and working on dev branch in project? How do I make migrations? What packages I can update?

My models:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_default_pk(cls):
        obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            name='No category was added',
            position=99
        )
        return obj.pk


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('shop name'), max_length=128)
    domain = models.CharField(_('domain'), max_length=128)
    active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('position'), default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='related_name_category',
                             default=Categories.get_default_pk())

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', 'name')
        verbose_name = _('shop')
        verbose_name_plural = _('shops')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The whole traceback after running `python3 manage.py makemigrations`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ArtemBoss/GitHubRepos/pricemon/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/ArtemBoss/GitHubRepos/pricemon/manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/constance/models.py", line 30, in <module>
signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_perm, dispatch_uid="constance.create_perm")
  AttributeError: module 'django.db.models.signals' has no attribute 'post_syncdb'
```

Comment: please share your models

Comment: I've added models

Comment: can you also add full traceback, I can't see anything wrong in models.

Comment: I added traceback

Comment: can you try `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`

Comment: The same thing happens

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you are using older version of django. `pip show django` run this on terminal and tell me version

Comment: 4.0.3 , I really have no idea how to fix it without changing the version

Comment: Hmm, can you search if you are using `signal` or `post_syncdb` somewhere in your model.py?

Comment: Even if it's using in models I can't change them. Mu task is to create categories model and relate it with shop models. After that make migrations and docker-compose up

Comment: if it's in models then you will have to use the django version that your company is using. I believe there would be a requirements.txt file

Comment: @shivankgtm May I solve the problem if I reinstall Django to tge newest version? Or I can handle this with venv?

Comment: venv should handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no model in your project uses `post_syncdb` as if so, it will prevent you from running the migrations command.

Also why can't you use an appropriate version of Django?

Comment: I added models and full traceback. I don't know, programmers told me we need to work with this version. Maybe problem in venv?

Comment: No, I don't think it's in the venv. Your project should be working with a defined version of Django. You shouldn't go for the latest for many reasons and stick with a specific version. Therefore, we always have a requirements.txt file to keep track of each package's versioning. I suggest what @shivankgtm said and ask your team what Django version they use.

Comment: So, the solution is to update all packages in requirements.txt file?